# How to write custom validation message for multiple inputs in a laravel form?

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

```
$validation = $request->validate([
            'title'=>'required',
            'description'=>'required',
            'type'=>'required',
            'building_plot_size'=>'required',
            'parking'=>'required',
            'contact'=>'required',
            'address'=>'required',
            'total_building_floors'=>'required_if:type,1',
            'community_house_type'=>'required_if:type,2',
            'total_single_houses'=>'required_if:community_house_type,1',
            'total_buildings'=>'required_if:community_house_type,2',
            'total_houses'=>'required_if:community_house_type,2',
            'floor_flat_ratio_houses.*'=>'required_with:total_building_floors',
            'house_building_ratio_houses.*'=>'required_with:total_buildings',
            'input_building_facility_key.*'=>'required_if:community_house_type,2',
            'input_building_facility_value.*'=>'required_if:community_house_type,2',
        ],
        [
            'title.required' => 'Enter Building Title',
            'description.required' => 'Enter Description Title',
            'type.required' => 'Select Building type',
            'building_plot_size.required' => 'Enter Plot Size is Required',
            'parking.required' => 'Select Parking is available or not',
            'contact.required' => 'Enter Building Contact Details',
            'address.required' => 'Enter Building Address',
            'total_building_floors.required_if' => 'Enter Total Building Floors',
            'community_house_type.required_if' => 'Select Community House Type',
            'total_single_houses.required_if' => 'Enter Total Single Houses in Community',
            'total_buildings.required_if' => 'Enter Total Buildings in a Community',
            'total_houses.required_if' => 'Enter Total Houses',
            'floor_flat_ratio_houses.required' => 'Enter Number of Flat per Floor ',
            'house_building_ratio_houses.required' => 'Enter Number of Houses per Building',
            'input_building_facility_key.required_if' => 'facility Key is required',
            'input_building_facility_value.required_if' => 'facility Value is required',
        ]);
```

I wanted to write the custom messages for input_building_facility_key and input_building_facility_value field. As the form values are coming as array

Answer (score 1):

if you use $this->validate() then you should write code something like this..

```
$rules = [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',


    ];

    $customMessages = [
        'name.required' => 'Your Message',
        'email.required'=>'Your Choice Message'

    ];

    $this->validate($request, $rules, $customMessages);
```